# Posting XMLHTTPRequest on window close

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've written [an XMPP client](http://ivan.vucica.net/zxmpp/) for the web, using the standard BOSH method to connect to the server.

I'm having an issue that user's connection stays open when user closes the window; I am unable to act upon detection of such an activity due to protocol peculiarities. One of the reasons BOSH was designed was to handle connection-loss-prone networks. Thus, losing BOSH (Comet) connection to the server is tolerated if another connection is opened within pre-specified timeframe. So, to truly disconnect the user, I'd have to send a disconnect message to the XMPP server via another XMLHTTPRequest.

Due to the asynchronous nature of XMLHTTPRequest, this is, as far as I know, impossible (and it might make it a privacy issue if it were possible). Or am I wrong? Can someone shed some light on how to send one final request to the server upon user closing the window?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack I've used:

```
window.onunload = function() {
  // I use Prototype to make the Ajax request,
  // but you can use any library you like.
  new Ajax.Request('closeConnection.php');
  alert('While they\'re reading this message, the Ajax should be complete.');
};
```

Comment: While a nice hack, this is not a solution since the window/tab close needs to be non-interactive.